# ¿Cómo evitar que las rrss redireccionen a la versión en inglés de mi sitio?

Tags: html, apache, facebook, .htaccess, twitter-api

Tengo una web en dos versiones, español e inglés, y a través de htaccess lo tengo configurado para desviar las visitas según el idioma del visitante de la siguiente forma:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Inglés 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ en/home [R,NC,L]

#Español
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ es/inicio [R,NC,L]

#General
RewriteRule ^/?$ en/home [R,NC,L]
```

El problema es que a la hora de promocionarme en redes sociales y postear el enlace a mi página (por ejemplo en un tuit o en una publicación de Facebook), estas redes se desvían a la versión inglesa, y la "preview" (Summary Card en Twitter) de la web incluye el título y descripción de la versión inglesa.

¿Se os ocurre alguna forma de cambiar este comportamiento?

Comment: prueba eliminando la linea de tu htaccess donde declaras el por defecto osea general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la [documentación de Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler?locale=es_ES#canonical), la información que se procesa (y por lo tanto la que se mostrará en los posts/tarjetas que se comparten) es la de la URL que se designe como canónica en el código HTML:

> **URL canónicas**
>
> Nuestro rastreador captura el contenido para compartir resolviendo la URL que designes como canónica.
>
> A modo de práctica recomendada, etiqueta todas las variaciones de una página con la URL canónica utilizando `og:url` (opción recomendada) o `link rel="canonical"`. El propio HTML de la URL canónica debe contener también una etiqueta `og:url` para designarse a sí mismo como recurso canónico.

Seguramente ya estás usando otras `meta` etiquetas Open Graph con la información que se mostrará, así que sólo tendrías que añadir una más con la URL canónica (y ya de paso, añadir un enlace con el atributo `rel="canonical"` en HTML).

Así en la versión en inglés de tu sitio, el código sería algo como esto (para la página de inicio):

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://TU_URL.com/en/home" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://TU_URL.com/en/home" />
```

y en la versión en español se vería así:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://TU_URL.com/es/inicio" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://TU_URL.com/es/inicio" />
```

---

Algunas notas sobre esta respuesta:

- Es más teoría que práctica. **No he podido comprobar si funciona o no en un servidor online**.
- Puede que no veas los resultados directamente porque Facebook guarda los valores que se comparten en la caché. Para ver los nuevos valores y borrar la caché de Facebook, visita esta URL: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ e introduce tu URL para ver cómo quedaría la nueva tarjeta.
- Está basada en la documentación de Facebook; no he encontrado nada sobre Twitter, aunque me imagino que funciona de una manera similar sólo que usando las meta etiquetas de Twitter (p.e.: `twitter:url`).